# Kubernetes - Scaling the resource failed with: Job.batch is invalid:

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, kubectl

I'm trying to delete an existent job using

```
kubectl delete job/job-name -n my-namespace
```

But this error is displayed

```
caling the resource failed with: Job.batch "kong-loop" is invalid:
spec.template: Invalid value: api.PodTemplateSpec{...}: field is
immutable; Current resource version 12189833
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution posted by @esnible does work in this scenario, but it is simpler do these  steps:

1. Delete job with cascade false

`kubectl delete job/jobname -n namespace --cascade=false`

2. Delete any pod that exists

`kubectl delete pod/podname -n namespace`

Solution found at in this google groups discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/YVmUgktoqtI

Answer (score 1):

*kubectl* does an HTTP PUT to the job during the delete process.  This PUT fails because the Job has gotten itself into an invalid state.  We must DELETE without PUTing.

Try

`kubectl proxy
curl -X DELETE localhost:8001/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/jobs/<jobname>`

Then kill the kubectl proxy process.  `namespace` is typically *default*